# Worksheet Change Event Firing when Error encountered in Dropdown

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dropdown data validation which will save the value of selected option into another cell location. This is done using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as range)
```

and when I try to input string into it, an error message will pop up which is expected since we cannot input anything into dropdown unless it's in the list. However, whenever I try to click 'Retry or Cancel' in the error message box, the Change event will fire again.

I  already have

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

but still not working. Can you please help me? I don't want to fire the Change event again if I encounter an error message due to the dropdown.

Here is the code and a sample scenario:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Cells(1, 2) = Target.Value
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Debug.Print Cells(1, 2).Value
End Sub
```

Cell(1, 1) = dropdown list which contains (A, B, C)

***Scenario 1:***
I will select A from the list, no error will be encountered.

Debug.print:

> A

***Scenario 2:***
I will input the character 'W' into the dropdown list, error will be encountered.

Error:

> The value does not match the data validation restrictions defined in the cell.

Debug.Print:

> A A A

As you can see, change event fired again twice after the Scenario 1.

Thanks in advance!

J

Comment: Cell(1,2) is not a data validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowing the change event to be fired if any cell changes in the worksheet.  You don't need the enable events restriction, just specify the target...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
      If Target.Value = "A" Or Target.Value = "B" Or Target.Value = "C" Then
         Cells(1, 2) = Target.Value
      End If
   End if
End Sub
```

Comment: That'll work but my problem is whenever some user input string/text into the dropdown menu which is not part of the list, the event will fire again.

Comment: Did you try the above?  They should get a "Retry, Cancel" option and if they cancel, they can choose from the list again.  It won't go into a loop.  Under your original, changing `Cells(1,2)` would trigger the event.

Comment: Tried it, clicked cancel then the event fired again once after the initial.

Comment: I see, so the first firing was because of I changed the value of the dropdown. Second firing was from the `Cells(1, 2) = target.value`. My question now is how to capture the error when a string/text was inputted in the dropdown so that I can stop the code from doing `Cells(1, 2) = target.value`?

Comment: See the edit above.  You can choose to do nothing if it doesn't meet criteria, however that is what the data validation is supposed to do.